Condition on $x$ such that $\sin \theta + \cos \theta = x$ implies $\sin^6 \theta + \cos^6 \theta = \frac{1}{4}\left(4-3(x^2-1)^2\right)$
Here is another confusing question from my telegram group of teachers where some are agree with option B and some A

If $\sin \theta + \cos \theta = x$ then
$$\sin^6 \theta + \cos^6 \theta = \frac{1}{4}\left(4-3(x^2-1)^2\right)$$
for
a: All real$\quad$
b: $x^2\leq 2\quad$
c: $x^2 \geq 2\quad$
d: None of these

First Idea So here the equation is $\sin^6 \theta + \cos^6 \theta$ both part are equal so it must satisfied for all values of x. I checked it by putting value of x in right side.
Second idea: while putting the value if I convert left part into \begin{equation}
(\sin{2\theta})^2 = (x^2 - 1)^2
\end{equation}
And $\sin{2\theta}$ is between $[0,1]$ so
$$ (x^2 - 1) \leq 1 $$
$$ x^2 \leq 2. $$
I used online site for latex and adding the original question with picture. Thanks in advance


Technically, $x$ can really be at most $\sqrt 2$ and is at least $-\sqrt 2$. This is because these are the possible maximum and minimum value of $\sin\theta+\cos\theta$.

The second condition also gives $x$ in the same range (as you have also realized). So the correct option is really b.

The complicated relation is an identity for all $\theta$, so the question reduces to ensuring the defn of $x$ is valid, hence $x^2\leq 2$ (by OP's and @YuzurihaInori's arguments). ... Probably. ... Note that $x^2\leq2$ (as opposed to $0\leq x^2\leq 2$) holds for purely-imaginary $x$. Presumably, an implicit condition (perhaps stated at the beginning of the problem set) is that $x$ and $\theta$ are real, and we're done; w/o this condition, $x^2\leq 2$ is no longer an appropriate restriction on $x$, since complex $\theta$ allows $x$ itself to be any complex number, making the answer (d).

@Blue Valid point! But what I can gather from circumstantial context is that they are meant to be just real. These kind of questions are really common in high school trigonometry, so that is really my guess.

@YuzurihaInori: "what I can gather from circumstantial context is that they are meant to be just real" ... Oh, I agree. I was just having some fun. :)

Please send me the telegram link

@IITRoorkee https://t.me/mathematicsTGTPGT

The wording is a bit strange here. If we write $p_x$ as the proposition "for all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, $\sin\theta+\cos\theta=x$ implies that $\sin^6\theta+\cos^6\theta=\dfrac{4-3(x^2-1)^2}{4}$", then $p_x$ is true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, because it is vacantly true for $x\in(-\infty,-\sqrt{2})\cup(\sqrt{2},+\infty)$. If we write instead $p_x$ as the proposition "for all $\theta\in\mathbb{C}$, ...", then $p_x$ is still true for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$ because it is an identity.

(cont'd) In conclusion, supposing that $x,\theta$ are real, even if I know that the questioner wants me to choose (b), it would be mathematically more correct to choose (a)... By the way, this is precisely why I hate the type of questions like "if $x^2+x+1=0$, then $x^3=?$".

Suppose $$\sin^6 \theta + \cos^6 \theta = \frac{1}{4}\left(4-3(x^2-1)^2\right)$$ for $\sin \theta + \cos \theta = x$.
The factorisation of LHS would be,
$$\sin^{6} \theta + \cos^{6} \theta = (\sin^{2} \theta + \cos^{2} \theta) \cdot (\sin^{4} \theta + \cos^{4} \theta - \sin^{2} \theta \cdot \cos^{2} \theta).$$
Then, after substitution of $x$ in RHS and simplifying,
$$\sin^{4} \theta + \cos^{4} \theta - \sin^{2} \theta \cdot \cos^{2} \theta = 1 - \frac{3}{4} \sin^{2} 2\theta.$$
$$\sin^{4} \theta + \cos^{4} \theta - \sin^{2} \theta \cdot \cos^{2} \theta =  1 - 3 \sin^{2} \theta \cdot \cos^{2} \theta$$
$$(\sin^{2} \theta + \cos^{2} \theta)^{2} = 1$$
Hence, the statement holds true for all values of $\theta$.
The range of $x$ for which the equation holds shall then be $[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$ since,
$$\sin \theta + \cos \theta \in [-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}] \quad \forall \, \theta$$
Hence, the statement holds true for all values of $x$ satisfying the inequality $x^{2} \leq 2$.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... In your "simplifying" step, the $1/4$ should be $1$. This carries through to the end, leaving a valid identity.

Thank you so all the participants. I am glad to discuss. I'm happy to get a clear vision on a tiny problem from all of users. Thanks you

Blue Thank you, for pointing out. I was miserably wrong. @Clup Titu Welcome, we are glad to help..

I don't see how this answers the question. The question is about the range of $x$, nto for $\theta$.

@Yuzuriha Inori, I have edited my answer, I guess this explains better.

That seems alright now. Thanks.

This is our duty @CiupTitu. And also thank you for the group link

Here's a slightly different way to do it (the one I alluded in the comments). It might seem a little overkill, but it will show a particularly interesting result.
First let me prove that $x=\sin\theta+\cos\theta$ implies $-\sqrt2\le x\le \sqrt2$. The proof is simply just noting that $$x=\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt2\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin\theta+\frac1{\sqrt2}\cos\theta\right)=\sqrt2\sin\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$ I will leave it to you to show that the bounds can be achieved.
Once we have established that, we look at $$\sin^6 \theta + \cos^6 \theta = \frac{1}{4}\left(4-3(x^2-1)^2\right)=:y_6$$
In what range does $y_6$ lie? I claim that $$\frac14\le y_6\le 1$$ In fact, I will prove a much more general statement. Define $$y_n=\sin^{2n}\theta+\cos^{2n}\theta$$ Then $$\frac1{2^{n-1}}\le y_n\le 1$$ First clearly $$\sin^{2n}\theta+\cos^{2n}\theta\le\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$$ For the lower bound, here's a fun inequality for $n>1$ (lots of proofs can be found here) $$\frac{a+b}{2}\le\left(\frac{a^n+b^n}{2}\right)^{1/n}$$ Placing $a=\sin^2\theta$ and $b=\cos^2\theta$, we get $$\frac1{2^{n-1}}\le y_n$$ Once again I will leave it to you to show that both of the bounds can be achieved.
Then we have $$\frac14\le \frac14(4-3(x^2-1)^2)\le 1$$ A little algebra now shows that we have $$-\sqrt2\le x\le \sqrt2$$ and thus the inequalities are the same and thus the relation holds true for all $0\le x^2\le 2$.

in the last step did you miss negative sign $(-\sqrt{2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{2})$

@CiupTitu Ah yes, a typo. Thanks.
